# Getting character values from an array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to practice some c++ stuff and have gotten stuck on something which has been difficult to google or find the answer too.

basically say we have:

```
char* myarray[] = {"string","hello", "cat"};
```

how would I got about say getting myarray[1] which is "string" and then traversing through the letter s t r i n g.

I was looking at vectors and wonder if that is the route to take or maybe taking myarray[1] and storing it into another array before iterating through it. What is the best way of doing this

Comment: First of all, `"string"` is saved in `myarray[0]`, not `myarray[1]` (arrays start at zero in C++). Second, have you tried a `vector` of `std::strings` instead? While this is not a real answer to your question, try to accustom yourself to the standard library, which will take some work from you.

Comment: Basically, _never_ say we have `char* x = "...";`.  String literals are immutable, and should be `char const*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(myarray[0]); i++) {
    printf("%c\n", myarray[0][i]);
}
```

Will print out

```
s
t
r
i 
n
g
```

If you're looking to practice C++ and *not C*, I suggest learning `std::string` and `std::vector`. They are not always the solution but usually using them first is the right answer. The memory layout of `std::vector<std::string>` will be different and it is important to understand this.

Comment: This is horrible.  If you really want to use the C style strings, then at least move the `strlen` out of the loop (and using pointers would be more idiomatic both in C and in C++).

Comment: @JamesKanze any compiler should move the strlen out of the loop for you, but I agree with you anyway

Comment: @Dave The compiler can only move `strlen` out of the loop if it knows what's in `strlen`.  The way most compilers I've seen are set up, they don't.

Comment: @James Any sane compiler will make this optimization. Here is a list of functions that GCC is particularly good at optimizing http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: @JacobParker Most compilers do _not_ make this optimization.  A compiler can make it in C, because C specifically allows `strlen` to be a macro (e.g. something like `#define strlen(s) __buildin__strlen(s)`).  C++ does not.

Comment: @James Both clang++ and g++ do on the most recent Ubuntu. What mainstream compiler do you have in mind?

Answer (score 4):

That's very easy in C++11 (using `std::string` rather than a pointer to an array of characters):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string myarray[] = {"string","hello", "cat"};
    for (auto c : myarray[0]) { std::cout << c << " "; }
}
```

Output ([live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2m2muG%240)):

```
s t r i n g
```